# Maya: Add namespace back to my node after remove

Tags: python, reference, namespaces, maya

I have an animation file which has a reference namespace "rig:", I need to remove the namespace before I export it, so I use the following code to remove the namespace and it work:

cmds.namespace( removeNamespace = ns[0], mergeNamespaceWithRoot = True)

Now, the problem is I need to add the namespace back, but couldn't find out how.  I tried to use add or set namespace, but it only add namespace if I create new object, it won't add it back to my existing nodes.  Anyone have ideas how it works?  Million thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First you can query the reference's resolved file path. This should be unique even if you have multiple references imported from the same path. You can do this by passing one of the reference's objects to:

```
resolvedPath = cmds.referenceQuery('myReferenceObject', f = True)
```

Now to switch the reference's namespace, you can pass the resolve path to this:

```
cmds.file(resolvedPath, e = True, namespace = 'myNewNamespace')
```

You can check in the documentation that using `cmds.namespace()` will actually error when trying to rename referenced nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Just set the namespace and then rename the object, as long as the the namespace is set the newly renamed object will be in the active namespace. You can also explictly specify the namespace in the rename command.  If you want to rename something into the root namespace use a leading colon.

Comment: "I have an animation file which has a reference namespace"
You cannot just rename reference objects willy nilly

Comment: He said his example code works, which means he's working on objects that have been added to the namespace that got in to the scene via the reference. It's possible to add items to the namespace created by a reference, although it's not possible to rename the read-only nodes in the reference

Comment: Thanks for your help!